# cx_Freeze : Python error in main script

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I want to create an executable of my script with cx_freeze.

I use steup.py:

```
import sys 
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executablesetup(
name = "balance",
version = "3.1",
description = "exported data integral",
executables = [Executable("balance1.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

Next I run it in cmd. And then when i start .exe in build folder i get :[image]

Im using Pyzo distribution.

What may couse such error ?

Comment: can't load the error image.

Comment: http://imgur.com/L9gOwMm here You are

Comment: There's a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/43/import-errors-when-using-cx_freeze-with) with freezing scipy, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I switched scipy simps with numpy trapz. I still got error but much smaler : which i take as a good sign :) http://imgur.com/IdMdIWv can u help me with this one ? Please.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in cx_freeze version that installs using pip.

Download prepackaged version from here (choose appropriate for your system version):
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze

Install 'wheel' using pip:

```
pip install wheel
```

And then install downloaded whl file using pip:

```
pip install cx_freeze_xxx.whl
```